# Does Google allow other people to use their "Did you mean" API?

Tags: python, api, spell-checking, google-api

I have been searching all over the Internet, but did not find that exact API.

I'd like to use their Did You mean feature for my own website.

Comment: Not really any answer so I will put it here. Last I checked the Yahoo search API allows you to do this so if you are stuck and can't do it with google there is always that option.

Comment: http://didyoumean.info/, you can use it by http://didyoumean.info/api?tld=com&q=sackoveflows (stack overflow), you can set TLD to return more relevant results if your website is not in English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

doSpellingSuggestion I believe is the api call. There is a good example [here](http://www.asp101.com/articles/jeremy/googlespell/default.asp)

*Update*
As people have noted, the link is broken. [Here is a Wayback Machine's archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20090319083335/http://www.asp101.com/articles/jeremy/googlespell/default.asp).

Comment: Link cited here is broken.

Answer (score 8):

Pygoogle has an api call for that

http://pygoogle.sourceforge.net/dist/doc/public/google-module.html#doSpellingSuggestion

```
>>> import google
>>> google.LICENSE_KEY = '...'
>>> google.doSpellingSuggestion('pithon')
'python'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's been a great Python example going around for awhile showing exactly how to implement this (in only 21 lines of code!): http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html It was shown at the Stackoverflow DevDays in Toronto, and I believe at some of the other locations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one in python that get the [didyoumean](https://github.com/bkvirendra/didyoumean) results