# Add spaces between words in spaceless string

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring

I'm on OS X, and in objective-c I'm trying to convert

for example, 
"Bobateagreenapple"

into 
"Bob ate a green apple"

Is there any way to do this efficiently? Would something involving a spell checker work?

EDIT: Just some extra information:
I'm attempting to build something that takes some misformatted text (for example, text copy pasted from old pdfs that end up without spaces, especially from internet archives like JSTOR). Since the misformatted text is probably going to be long... well, I'm just trying to figure out whether this is feasibly possible before I actually attempt to actually write system only to find out it takes 2 hours to fix a paragraph of text.

Comment: +1 Very interesting question. I'm interesting to see the solution for this, though I can't think of one. The only way that may be considered is simply going through all the letters and chopping off the word when it is compared into a dictionary as a complete word... though this method would fail pretty quickly.

Comment: That could also be interpreted (admittedly nonsensically) as "Bob a tea green apple".

Comment: @Ferruccio : You've demonstrated exactly why this would be fraught with trouble... and that was just with the example text posted in this question. There would be real-life examples that *did* make sense, but were still wrong too.

Comment: @Ferruccio: +1 for stealing my example before i wrote it >:(

Comment: Does the text have punctuation? Obviously this makes it a lot easier, since you can handle each sentence (fragment) separately.

Comment: Great question! Maybe Google Did you mean he?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691275/does-google-allow-other-people-to-use-their-did-you-mean-api

Comment: Great question! Maybe Google Did you mean he?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691275/does-google-allow-other-people-to-use-their-did-you-mean-api

Answer (score 2):

One possibility, which I will describe this in a non-OS specific manner, is to perform a search through all the possible words that make up the collection of letters.

Basically you chop off the first letter of your letter collection and add it to the current word you are forming. If it makes a word (eg dictionary lookup) then add it to the current sentence. If you manage to use up all the letters in your collection and form words out of all of them, then you have a full sentence. But, you don't have to stop here. Instead, you keep running, and eventually you will produce all possible sentences.

Pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
FindWords(vector<Sentence> sentences, Sentence s, Word w, Letters l)
{
    if (l.empty() and w.empty())
        add s to sentences;
        return;
    if (l.empty())
        return;
    add first letter from l to w;
    if w in dictionary
    {
        add w to s;
        FindWords(sentences, s, empty word, l)
        remove w from s
    }
    FindWords(sentences, s, w, l)
    put last letter from w back onto l
}
```

There are, of course, a number of optimizations you could perform to make it go fast. For instance checking if the word is the stem of any word in the dictionary. But, this is the basic approach that will give you all possible sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Solving this problem is much harder than anything you'll find in a framework. Notice that even in your example, there are other "solutions": "Bob a tea green apple," for one.

A very naive (and not very functional) approach might be to use a spell-checker to try to isolate one "real word" at a time in the string; of course, in this example, that would only work because "Bob" happens to be an English word.

This is not to say that there is no way to accomplish what you want, but the way you phrase this question indicates to me that it might be a lot more complicated than what you're expecting. Maybe someone can give you an acceptable solution, but I bet they'll need to know a lot more about what exactly you're trying to do.

Edit: in response to your edit, it would probably take less effort to run some kind of OCR tool on a PDF and correct its output than it would just to correct what this system might give you, let alone program it

Comment: It could also be "Boba tea…", which is a fairly popular drink that does indeed come in apple flavors, so even a sophisticated analysis of how often phrases occur and in what contexts could get thrown off.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a solution, the code is avaible on code project:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/704003/How-to-add-spaces-between-spaceless-strings

My idea was to prioritize results that use up most of the characters (preferable all of them) then favor the ones with the longest words, because 2,3 or 4 character long words can often come up by chance from leftout characters. Most of the times this provides the correct solution.

To find all possible permutations I used recursion. The code is quite fast even with big dictionaries (tested with 50 000 words).

Comment: Link only answers are not welcome in our community. Please add relevant code here