# Google Address Correction

Tags: c++, rest, search, maps

For my project I need a way to correct addresses, with the uses of Google services. The addresses themselves are valid, but are very likely to include single or multiple (spelling) mistakes. I'm implementing the whole system under C++ (QT).

I did try using the http://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?lang=en&hl=en REST service, but it turned out that it just "corrects single words" and does not use the google "*did you mean*" suggestions.

Is there or can anyone think of a good way to do this programatically? **Specifically is there a way to access the google maps or google search API to get the correction suggestion (*"did you mean*..").**

Worst case, I'll have to html crawl the http request results, but this is a very slow and not very stable method (won't work anymore, if google changes formating or layout)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm pretty new here, I apologize in advance if the post is not written very clearly or according to local standards

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are looking for is called "Spelling Suggestion". Here's a thread that might help you get what you need.

[Does Google allow other people to use their "Did you mean" API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691275/does-google-allow-other-people-to-use-their-did-you-mean-api)